# RoboBrowser Search Form

Tags: python, forms, post, robobrowser

I want to search a form but get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute`

```html
<form method="POST" action="liste.php">
          <input size="20" id="searchfield" maxlength="100" name="suche" onchange="clear_input();" accesskey="s" title="Bitte beachten Sie, dass die Suchanfrage mindestens 3 Zeichen lang sein muss!">
          <input type="submit" value="" class="gosearch">
        </form>
```

My python code is:

```
# Search the Website
formSearch = browser.get_form(action=('/liste.php'))
formSearch['suche'].value = 'Maus'
browser.submit_form(formSearch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML shows that the `action` attribute is set to `'liste.php'`, without the leading slash. You do need to match that:

```
formSearch = browser.get_form(action='liste.php')
```

Comment: That was the solution! sometimes its only one false character! :D THX